# How to use the jsx conditionals in react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to render a button and a component when some condition is true within the render method.

Below is my code,

```
render = () =>  {
    <div>
        {(this.state.exists || this.state.active) &&
            <button>
                <svg>something</svg>
            </button>}
        {this.state.exists || this.state.active) &&
            <ChildComponent
                first_val={first_val}/>}
    </div>
}
```

The above code works. As you see from code above i am using the same condition to render or not the button and component. i am duplicating the condition. so i was trying to do it like below and it throws error of the curly bracket.

```
render = () =>  {
    <div>
        {(this.state.exists || this.state.active) &&
            <button>
                <svg>something</svg>
            </button>
            <ChildComponent
                first_val={first_val}/>}
    </div>
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this or better way of using conditionals here. Could someone provide an insight into this. thanks.

Comment: One more `&& <ChildComponent..../>`

Comment: @Jai — That will **discard** the `<button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression can only evaluate as *one thing*.

You're trying to create *two* things: a button **and** a child component.

You need to wrap them in a data structure such as [a `React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

```
{
    (this.state.exists || this.state.active) &&
    <>
        <button>
            <svg>something</svg>
        </button>
        <ChildComponent first_val={first_val}/>
    </>
}
```

It's like returning an array `[1, 2]` instead of `1 2` from a function.

Answer (score 1):

This is because sub elements elements need to be in a single element scope

try replacing your

```
render = () =>  {
    <div>
        {(this.state.exists || this.state.active) &&
            <button>
                <svg>something</svg>
            </button>
            <ChildComponent
                first_val={first_val}/>}
    </div>
}
```

with

```
render = () =>  {
        <div>
            {(this.state.exists || this.state.active) &&(
    <React.Fragment>
                <button>
                    <svg>something</svg>
                </button>
                <ChildComponent
                    first_val={first_val}/>
    </React.Fragment>
    )}
        </div>
    }
```